# Php array inside array foreach loop access element by field

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array eg orders. This array has 2 arrays with order details

How can I loop through each order and retrieve fields from all orders?

Here is my code

```
foreach($order as $row)

 {?>

  <div><?php $order['order_id'] ?></div>

<?

}
```

It doesn't show anything because it access the first array which holds the orders. Is there a way to access the second array inside the div tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($order as $row)

 {?>

 <div><?php echo $row['order_id'] ?></div>

 <?

 }
```

Comment: Yes that solved the issue. Will mark correct soon. Thanks